# How to add firebase dependencies in android app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I want to add firebase to my project, this is my dependencies:

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.11'

    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofit_version}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofit_version}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${retrofit_version}"

    //http interceptor
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${interceptor_version}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${interceptor_version}"

    // Material Dialog Library
    implementation 'com.shreyaspatil:MaterialDialog:2.1'
    // Material Design Library
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    // Lottie Animation Library
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0'

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0"

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.3.0"

    // Annotation processor
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.3.0"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6"
    // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.6"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1"

    //dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"

    //http interceptor
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${interceptor_version}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${interceptor_version}"

    //Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

    //Kodein Dependency Injection
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:6.2.1"
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:6.2.1"

    implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:1.7.5'

    implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'

//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mayuce:LottieAlertDialog:1.1'

    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.9.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.9.0-alpha03'

    //Rx java
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.11'

    //dexter
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'

    //Location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.prabhat1707:EasyWayLocation:2.0'

    //Aws
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.18.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.18.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.18.0'

    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:Google-Places-AutoComplete-EditText:0.0.8'
    //   implementation project(':maplibrary')

    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4-commons:0.10.8'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.bitvale:lightprogress:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.timigod:android-chat-ui:v0.1.4'

    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'

    implementation 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'

//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')

    // Declare the dependencies for the Firebase Cloud Messaging and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

But when I want to add firebase I got this error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:12.0.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

And also I added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the bottom of `build.gradle` in app level, and inside build.gradle project level:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                    details.useVersion "12.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of dependencies. I suggest breaking your code base up into a few submodules and having them interact via interfaces.

Comment: Hey @Jameson, thanks for your reply, can you explained with an exalpe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed my issue by updating all packages to the latest version and remove some code from build.gradle file in app-level and project level, like below: in project-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.61"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle in app-level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

def room_version = "2.2.5"
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
def arch_version = "2.1.0"
def coroutines_version = "1.3.5"
def dagger_version = "2.27"
def retrofit_version = "2.8.1"
def interceptor_version = "4.2.1"
def glide_version = "4.11.0"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.development.allanproject"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.11'

    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofit_version}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofit_version}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${retrofit_version}"

    //http interceptor
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${interceptor_version}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${interceptor_version}"

    // Material Dialog Library
    implementation 'com.shreyaspatil:MaterialDialog:2.1'
    // Material Design Library
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    // Lottie Animation Library
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0'

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    // Annotation processor
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    //dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"

    //http interceptor
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${interceptor_version}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${interceptor_version}"

    //Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    //Kodein Dependency Injection
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:6.2.1"
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:6.2.1"

    implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:1.7.5'

    implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mayuce:LottieAlertDialog:1.1'

    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.8.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.9.0-alpha03'

    //Rx java
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9'

    //dexter
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'

    //Location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.prabhat1707:EasyWayLocation:2.0'

    //Aws
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.18.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.18.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.18.0'

    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:Google-Places-AutoComplete-EditText:0.0.8'
    //   implementation project(':maplibrary')

    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4-commons:0.10.8'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.bitvale:lightprogress:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.timigod:android-chat-ui:v0.1.4'

    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'

    implementation 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:2.0.1'

}
```